# Getting translation table of organisms through Entrez direct (or other CLIs)

Tags: phylogenetics, entrez

I have a long list of NCBI taxonomic ids for organisms and I want to write a script to get their corresponding translation tables. Is there a way to do this through Entrez?

(packages in R, Python etc. would be fine too)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this idea. So, the information for the translation table of any particular organism can be found on its page on the Taxonomy Browser: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi

If I search a taxid into the website, eg 7227, the page for *Drosophila melanogaster* will come up but the URL will remain unmodified. However, you can get a modified URL specific to a taxid by appending ?mode=Info&id=*your_taxid* to the above URL. Eg for *D. melanogaster* again, it has this unique URL for its Taxonomy browser page: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=7227

Since you have a list of taxids, you can programmatically access Taxonomy browser pages by modifying the URL in the way I said. To programmatically get the translation tables of *D. melanogaster* with this approach, use the urllib package in Python.

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=7227"
weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = weburl.read().decode("utf-8")  # decode because page returned in binary

data_s = data.split('<')

for d in data_s:
    if "Translation table" in d:
        print(d.split('>')[1])
```

The output is:

```
Translation table 1 (Standard)
Translation table 5 (Invertebrate Mitochondrial)
```

This will work for one taxid. But you have a list of them. However, with this approach in mind, it's elementary to construct a Python function for getting the Translation table of all your taxids.

```
import urllib.request

my_taxids = ['7227','9606','10090']

def get_translation_table(taxid):
    url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=" + taxid
    weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = weburl.read().decode("utf-8")

    data_s = data.split('<')

    tr_table = []

    for d in data_s:
        if "Translation table" in d:
            tr_table += [d.split('>')[1]]

    return tr_table

your_tables = list(map(get_translation_table,my_taxids))

print(your_tables)
```

The output is:

```
[['Translation table 1 (Standard)', 'Translation table 5 (Invertebrate Mitochondrial)'], ['Translation table 1 (Standard)', 'Translation table 2 (Vertebrate Mitochondrial)'], ['Translation table 1 (Standard)', 'Translation table 2 (Vertebrate Mitochondrial)']]
```

And if you want the results nicely formatted into a pandas dataframe, just add:

```
import pandas as pd
```

To the top of the script, and

```
t = pd.DataFrame(your_tables,columns=["Nuclear","Mitochondrial"])
print(t)
```

To the bottom. Output of this print (if you have too many taxids use the head method instead so not everything prints):

```
                          Nuclear                                     Mitochondrial
0  Translation table 1 (Standard)  Translation table 5 (Invertebrate Mitochondrial)
1  Translation table 1 (Standard)    Translation table 2 (Vertebrate Mitochondrial)
2  Translation table 1 (Standard)    Translation table 2 (Vertebrate Mitochondrial)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find them here at least:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Utils/wprintgc.cgi

You can download the complete list of codes (using FTP) [here](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/entrez/misc/data/gc.prt).

However, to link a specific organism to a specific codon usage table, you'll need to do a bit of extra work. Perhaps the [script here](https://github.com/sleyn/get_taxonomy_by_NCBI_TaxID) can give you a starting point?

Comment: What I was really looking for was some way to input the taxonomic id/name of an organism and have its translation table returned. NCBI does seem to have this data for specific taxa, because a button on the page you linked ('Genetic Code in Taxonomy Tree') matches organisms with translation tables.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to code that together using an ASN.1 parser I guess?